# adding inbound rule to existing aws security group using node js sdk

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

```
const instanceParams = {
    GroupId: "sg-0bd930929e79ecbe0",
    IpPermissions: [
        {
            FromPort: 22,
            IpProtocol: "tcp",
            IpRanges: [
                {
                    CidrIp: "203.0.113.0/24",
                    Description: "SSH access from the LA office"
                }
            ],
            ToPort: 22
        }
    ],

    SecurityGroups:["testSecuityGroup"] // for custom security group testing
};
```

i am trying to add a inbound rule to a existing security group this parameters helps me to create an inbound rule

---

it create the type as SSH
but i want to change the type [Note there are several available type such as SMPT , DNS(TCP), DNS(UDP) etc]

how to define type for as traffic access